# Moving a block to a different block

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layout, blocks, xml

I'm using a module of Amasty that adds a block to my catalog product view's content reference. This puts in on the top of the page, but I want to move it just above the upsell in the `product.info` block.

I'm trying to unset this using `unsetChild` and inserting it just above `product.info.upsell`, but I can't get it to work. The block keeps appearing above the whole `product.info` block or below it.

This is my code:

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>amprevnext_prevnext</name></action>
            <action method="insert">
                <blockName>amprevnext_prevnext</blockName>
                <siblingName>product.info.upsell</siblingName>
                <after>0</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the `awprevnext_prevnext` is added to the `content` block and not to the `product.info` block.

Here's what you should do:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>amprevnext_prevnext</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="insert"><block>amprevnext_prevnext</block></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

However, this won't be enough because the `product.info` original template `catalog/product/view.phtml` does not render all the child block automatically by calling `echo $this->getChildHtml();`

Thus you need to add the following to your custom theme `catalog/product/view.phtml` template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('amprevnext_prevnext'); ?>
```

You need to add that code before the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
```

Comment: I tried the whole `<reference name="product.info">` indeed, but didn't think of also including it in my `catalog/product/view.phtml`.. Thanks, this fixed it!